# Subset closest to X (knapsack problem)

Tags: summation, combinations, recursion, discrete-optimization, python

Given a list of numbers e.g. [1,2,3,4,5,6] and a positive integer X, how can I find out what numbers from my list are required to get X and if not get X then the closest to X? This is for a python function, but I understand it is a mathematical issue.

> if A is [12, 79, 99, 91, 81, 47] and s is 150, it will return [12, 91,
> 47] as 12+91+47 is 150

> if A is [15, 79, 99, 6, 69, 82, 32] and s is
> 150 it will return [69, 82] as 69+82 is 151, and there is no subset of
> A whose sum is 150.

```
>>> def closest_sum(A, X):
...     closest = {}
...     closest_distance = None
...     for S in A:
...         if closest_distance is None or abs(sum(S) - X) < closest_distance:
...             closest = sum(S)
...             closest_distance = abs(sum(S) - X)
...     return closest
...
>>> closest_sum([{1, 3}, {4, 5, 6}], 5)
4
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which is known to be NP-complete (loosely meaning that if a polynomial-time algorithm exists to solve this problem, then many other hard problems could be solved in polynomial time).

Since this problem is NP-complete, there is essentially no faster solution than to iterate over all subsets of $A$ and check their distance from $X$. The pseudocode would look like this:

```
function closest_sum(A, X):
    closest = {};
    closest_distance = infinity;
    for every subset S of A:
        sum = sum of elements in S;
        if abs(sum - x) < closest_distance:
            closest = S;
            closest_distance = abs(sum - x);
    return closest
```

This takes exponential time of course, since there are $2^{|A|}$ subsets $S\subseteq A$.

Comment: See the code I have added to my original post. How would python code or pseudo code look if I wanted to return a list of values that were required to get the sum or the closest to the sum? Also, why does my function after following your pseudo code give 15 rather than 151 when using this array: [15, 79, 99, 6, 69, 82, 32]

Comment: I am iterating through every subset S of A (all $2^{|A|}$ of them) while you are just iterating through elements $S$ of $A$.

Comment: In terms of code, what do you mean by for every subset in A?

Comment: Furthermore, I wonder if there is a recursive approach to this all

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem via mixed integer linear programming as follows.  Let binary decision variable $y_i$ indicate whether item $i$ is selected.  The problem is to minimize $$\left|\sum_i i y_i - X\right|,$$ which you can linearize by introducing
nonnegative variables $s$ and $t$, and minimizing $s+t$ subject to
$$\sum_i i y_i - X = s - t.$$
This approach is generally much faster than brute force.

Comment: I have never come across this style of writing expressions and sadly do not understand what you have written well. I understand what you mean by brute force, I was thinking perhaps a recursive method. Marcelgoh's answer to this question seems really good but as you can see from my original post which I have edited, I have failed to implement such that the closest is in fact 151 for the numbers in my example as I get 154 instead and do not return the numbers used to get to 154

Comment: Then I instead recommend that you mimic the dynamic programming approach to the 0-1 knapsack problem.  That is, condition on whether item $n$ is included or not.